# Allow user to point CNAME to web app with SSL

Tags: ssl, dns, cname

I have a web app, and when users sign up, we give them their own subdomain, e,g, user1.website.example

We do this with a wildcard ssl for *.website.example

However, users are requesting custom domains.

So we plan on letting them point a CNAME to our system.

So when the user creates a CNAME "register.user1website.example" points to "user1.website.example", we pull that CNAME from the db and server the correct content - all works hunky dory...

BUT How do we allow the users domain to have a SSL?

Our system auto redirects from http to https, so they would get an insecure warning. Obviously, for the moment we have stopped the redirect, but we want everyone to have a SSL.

We're also talking about 10k+ users, so I don't want to have to have the domain added into Plesk and Lets Encrypt, as it changes all the time, and it would be a nightmare for management.

Comment: "BUT How do we allow the users domain to have a SSL?" Nothing different from all other cases, you need to have certificates per name (or a certificate with multiple names). Also your question is offtopic here as not related for now to programming. You might get better help on [sf] or [webmasters.se] but first read their help section to see what is on topic there.

Comment: OK thanks - trying to avoid a certificate per name unless its easy to manage. When you say "or a certificate with multiple names" - is it possible to hjave a SSL that covers any domain pointing to the server?

Comment: There is no magic answer here unfortunately: if you want custom domains and SSL, you will need certificates for each domain, and either you will create them with LetsEncrypt or users will have to upload them. You will need to automate that, perhaps you can do that more easily using some reverse proxy in front of your Plesk.

Comment: You have have a certificate with typically 100 names in it, any name for wish you can prove you control them. You can also have wildcards, like `*.example.com` but note tha a wildcard only matches a single label, and no, you can not have a wildcard of just `*` for any name. Your system has to generate new certificates when new names are created.